# H2 and EclipseLink - very slow on tables with one row

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink, h2

I have 7 tables and some tables are empty and some has only one row. In table maximum 5 columns, no any extra indexes and I make quite simple SQL queries.

This is how I run h2.

```
java -jar h2-1.3.176.jar
```

Queries are generated and executed by eclipselink 2.6.3. These are my settings in persistence.xml

```
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.initial" value="5"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.min" value="5"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost//home/somepath;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions" value="true"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.left-join-fetch" value="true"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

So every SQL query is executed about one second(!). Besides I hear that for every SQL query hard drive is working hard.

However, when I in H2 webconsole press connect to the same DB, then my java program works very fast. It works fast until I press disconnect in webconsole. How to explain this?

Comment: start taking actual time measurements, as I doubt anyone can help with unknown queries on unknown tables with unknown parameters and unknown timings.  if you execute the same query over and over, what is the average and the range of times you get?  What difference does having the console open make to this result?  What difference does having logging turned on to FINE do for your results?

Comment: @Chris The problem is not in query. The problem is in H2. Maybe something wrong with its mode. Because select a,b,c from d in table with 1 row can't continue about one second with serious hard drive load. And besides everything works fine when I just connect to H2 via web console. Only connect - without any queries in web console.